# jQuery, wrap "egg" in tags if whole word is "chickeneggs"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have some text:

`I like chickeneggs but not normal eggs` and I need to wrap `eggs` in `<i></i>` tags if the whole word is `chickeneggs` but not `eggs`.

So my expected result is:

`I like chicken<i>eggs</i> but not eggs`.

I have thought about using regex but I'm not sure on the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match `chickeneggs`, capture `chicken` and `eggs` and then reformat with back reference; Here use `g` to match globally:

> global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first
>   match

and `i` to match regardless of case, see more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
var s = "I like chickeneggs but not normal eggs, but also ChickenEggs";

console.log(
  s.replace(/(chicken)(eggs)/gi, "$1<li>$2</li>")
)
```

Comment: Okay great. This works. How could I improve the above code to keep the formatting applied to the current selection. So if `chickeneggs` was `ChickenEggs` in some place.

Comment: I do not quite understand, do you mean there are multiple occurrences or you want to ignore the case? You might need flags such as global `g` or ignore case `i` with `/chicken(eggs)/i`. It would be easy to see if you can give an example.

Comment: Multiple occurrences. But I want one replace method. So the replace method needs to match `chickeneggs` and `ChickenEggs`

Comment: I guess you need flags `g` and `i`